# How to find min, max data rate of pcap file

Tags: networking, wireshark, tshark

I have pcap file and I want to find min and max data rate.
I use Capinfos, it shows only average data rate. I would ask how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "max" - the maximum per second, per minute, per hour? At any instant either data is being transmitted at full speed or it is not, so for a short enough interval the answer is the speed of the interface, and likewise the minimum is  probably zero.

Comment: I mean maximum per second. How can I compute that?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
tshark -tad -nq -z 'io,stat,1,BYTES' -r file.pcap |
  grep '^| *[0-9]' |
  sort -t'|' -k3n |
  sed -n '1p;$p'
```

Where `tshark` with `-z 'io,stat,1,BYTES'` gives you an `io` `stat`istics report with `BYTES` count for every `1` second timeslice, `grep` extracts the lines with the data, `sort` sorts them on the byte column and `sed` extracts the `1`<sup>st</sup> (minimum) and last (`$`, maximum) line, giving you something like:

```
| 2021-10-09 11:51:54 |    52 |
| 2021-10-09 11:51:47 | 14325 |
```